# Find n coordinates in a d-dimensional space, where each point is in an equal distance from every other point?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Is it possible to find n coordinates in a d-dimensional space, where each point is in an equal distance from every other point? Is there a formula for that? If not, what is the best solution to have the pairwise distance between all the pints as close as possible (instead of equal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find $d+1$ points that are the same distance apart, like four points in $\Bbb R^3$ that form a regular tetrahedron.  In $\Bbb R^n$ we call it a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Cartesian_coordinates_for_regular_n-dimensional_simplex_in_Rn) and the article gives how to calculate Cartesian coordinates.  For more points you have to specify what you mean by close to equal.  What would be your solution for six points in $\Bbb R^2$?  Would a regular hexagon be the right answer?  You can certainly distribute $n$ points around a $d-1$ sphere "reasonably evenly", but some pairs will be about a diameter apart while some will be closer.

Comment: Thank you @ross for your answer. I am aware of simplex for n points in n-1 dimensional space. What I am interested in is having it for a d (d>>n) dim space. A solution in 2D for 6 points would be an arrangement where the average of pairwise distance between all points is minimum. I don't know how it would look like though. It might be all equally positioned around a circle or not. I can not tell for sure if that makes the averaged pairwise distance minimum. Maybe we could optimize such a loss and see what Will we end up with. But I prefer an exact solution. That's why I am asking this question

Comment: You can't just ask to minimize the pairwise distance differences because you can just shrink the configuration.  You need to do something like the standard deviation of the distances. Configuration problems are hard.  For large numbers you might do best to take the equivalent of a region of hexagonal close pack.

Comment: True, we need to set a minimum distance first. Otherwise it will collapse. Std also sounds good. Is there a guarantee about an n-point d-dimensional hexagon? how can one find the coordinates of such a hexagonal close packing?

Comment: If you define almost equal in terms of maximum difference between distances divided by maximum distance, I think this is (almost) equivalent to the packing of $n-$balls in an $n-1$ sphere.  For $n$ reasonably larger than $d$ the maximum distance will be the diameter of the sphere less the diameter of a ball.  The minimum will be the diameter of a ball.  If you look at [pacomania](http://www.packomania.com/) for circles in circles you will see that it is hard.  I suspect in higher dimensions it is worse, but do not know.

Comment: I see...thank's for the info. Need to think about it more...